# App build with Cordova/Phonegap stuck on black screen after splash, on first load after installation

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I am building a app with Cordova/Phonegap and also using a chcp plugin in it. when I open it for the first time after installation, the app is stuck on a black screen after the splash screen.

When I close the app and start it again, it works fine but just with a 9-10 seconds delay in the startup, where I have extended the time for splash screen to 10 second to avoid the black screen.

Here is the `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.storehippo.profitdeals" versionCode="103" version="1.0.3">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>CHCP splash Test</description>
    <author email="akshay.tiwari@mausis.com" href="http://cordova.io">Akshay Tiwari</author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
        <string>103</string>

    </gap:config-file>
<chcp>
            <config-file url="http://s3.amazonaws.com/mystore.in/s/55d178025c64d45531612809/ms.mobile_app_themes/560bd8ec31fec3dd1dd66fb7/chcp.json"/>
    </chcp>
    <gap:platform name="android"/>
    <gap:platform name="ios"/>
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
    <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
    <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="false"/>
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="10000"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000"/>
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent"/>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
    <icon src="nocon.png"/>
    <icon src="icons/ios/reader-57-1.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="icons/ios/reader-72-1.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="icons/ios/reader-76-1.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="icons/ios/reader-114-1.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="icons/ios/reader-120-1.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="icons/ios/reader-144-1.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="icons/ios/reader-152-1.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="icons/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="icons/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="icons/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="icons/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash.png"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"/>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-hot-code-push-plugin" source="npm" version="1.0.4"/>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" version="1.1.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" version="1.2.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" version="1.1.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" version="1.1.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-push-notification" source="npm" version="2.5.2" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" version="3.0.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" version="2.0.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" version="1.0.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" source="npm" version="2.2.2" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" source="npm" version="2.2.4" />
</widget>
```

Comment: some code would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

When you say stuck on a black screen do you mean its really stuck and you must force close the app or it just shows a black screen and then the app loads right afterwards?

I have an issue  with first loads after installation where a black screen will usually (maybe always) show on first install of the app after the splash screen for a second or 2 and thereafter will load as intended but it doesn't get stuck with proper parameters (just shows the black screen as mentioned for a few seconds). Subsequent re-opens of the app don't give such an issue (just happens on initial install)...I am still in search of fixing that issue as well despite it not being major.

I see you are using version `<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" version="3.0.0" />` 
I had issues with the newer version of the plugin for a different issue and someone on here suggested using an older version and it cleared it up. Perhaps you can try
 `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="2.0.0" source="npm" />` ... Also you are using `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>` Which means you need to manually hide the splash screen. for jquery mobile use on index.html before the cdn

`<script>document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 2000);
    }<script>`

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

I'm not sure what platform you are coding with but that is something to also consider. Also you could try using `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem that you have not figured out what it is, but after splashscreen.hide the screen is black, is a crosswalk compatibility error and the splash screen of the cord. How much must use it to make it work but it is not the best way.

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
function onDeviceReady() {
  navigator.splashscreen.show();
  if (navigator.splashscreen) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("fixblack").innerHTML += '&nbsp;';
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="fixblack"></div>
```

Comment: I hope you give to understand

Comment: Thanks for your answer - what do you mean by 'splash screen of the cord'?